# Should integer values be passed to floating point user defined literals?

Tags: c++, c++11, implicit-conversion, user-defined-literals

I'm playing around with user-defined-literals (with GCC 4.7).

```
double operator"" _lb(long double n)
{
    return n * 0.453592; // convert pounds to kilos
}
```

This works fine when passing it a floating point literal (e.g. `42.0_lb`) however when I try to pass an integer literal (e.g. `42_lb`) I get the following error:

> error: unable to find numeric literal operator 'operator"" _lb'

Shouldn't my definition of `_lb` cause an implicit conversion between the parameter to `long double` (as it would with regular functions)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, such implicit conversion doesn't apply in this case. As per [lex.ext]p3, a user-defined-intergal-literal can only be processed by a literal operator taking `unsigned long long` or by a raw literal operator (that takes `const char*`) or a literal operator template.

Comment: @Motti [N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) has the text I quoted as well. (Link taken from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11)).